# When calling EndDialogAsync on child dialog, ResumeDialogAsync doesn't get called on parent

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

I have two dialogs **ParentDialog** and **ChildDialog** both of them derives from **[ComponentDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.componentdialog?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)**, the parent is overriding **[OnBeginDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.componentdialog.onbegindialogasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)** and in there is invoking the child:

```
protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> OnBeginDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
   return await innerDc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ChildDialog), options, cancellationToken);
}
```

In the child, I am making some requests and after I am done, I call `innerDc.EndDialogAsync(result,cancellationToken);`. In the parent I am overriding **[ResumeDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.componentdialog.resumedialogasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)**:

```
public override Task<DialogTurnResult> ResumeDialogAsync(DialogContext outerDc, DialogReason reason, object result = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
    return base.ResumeDialogAsync(outerDc, reason, result, cancellationToken);
}
```

The documentation states that **[ResumeDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialog.resumedialogasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_Dialog_ResumeDialogAsync_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_DialogContext_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_DialogReason_System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)** is a:

> Method called when an instance of the dialog is being returned to from another dialog that was started by the current instance using BeginDialogAsync(). If this method is NOT implemented then the dialog will be automatically ended with a call to EndDialogAsync(). Any result passed from the called dialog will be passed to the current dialog's parent.

My question is, why is this method not called at all, am I missing something?

Thanks for taking the time in reading. I hope I was clear enough and appreciate any help.

Comment: were you able to resolve your issue? Do you still need help?

Comment: Hi @ranusharao

I was able to resolve the issue, but i ended up using another approach, thanks for asking. 

Regards.